# wstring to LPARAM and WPARAM

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to populate the members of a struct:

```
typedef struct SPEVENT
{
    SPEVENTENUM        eEventId : 16;
    SPEVENTLPARAMTYPE  elParamType : 16;
    ULONG       ulStreamNum;
    ULONGLONG   ullAudioStreamOffset;
    WPARAM      wParam;
    LPARAM      lParam;
} SPEVENT;
```

The information on how to use this is sparse. The only examples for populating it are from other users, but nothing official.

The app receiving this event should get the string. With my approach, it doesn't work: The string is "".

Can anybody tell me if he spots anything obvious wrong in my attempt?

```
wstring wsBookmark = L"MyBookmark";

CSpEvent nBookmarkEvent;
nBookmarkEvent.eEventId = SPEI_TTS_BOOKMARK;
nBookmarkEvent.elParamType = SPET_LPARAM_IS_STRING;
nBookmarkEvent.ullAudioStreamOffset = 0;
nBookmarkEvent.lParam = _wtol(wsBookmark.c_str());
nBookmarkEvent.wParam = (LPARAM)wsBookmark.c_str();
```

As I have explained, there doesn't seem to be any official guide on how to populate these members.

What I found so far are these user codes:

https://github.com/m-toman/SALB/blob/master/sapi/htstts.cpp
In this link I see this:

```
CHECKASSERTId(( !wcscmp( (WCHAR*)Event.lParam, szwBMarkStr ) ), tpr, IDS_STRING9);
```

But I have no idea if that would help me.

Thank you for any input or help!!

Comment: `lParam` and `wParam` string pointers are only valid for as long as `wsBookmark` is valid; you'd need to check if that is warranted.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. wsBookmark is valid.

Comment: It need not be string data or pointers see __SPEI_TTS_BOOKMARK__ from here for documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms717254%28v%3dvs.85%29  For more docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms720434(v%3Dvs.85)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SPEVENT` struct is [documented on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms720434(v=vs.85)).

In your case, the documentation for the [`SPET_LPARAM_IS_STRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms717255(v=vs.85)) flag says:

> SPET_LPARAM_IS_STRING
>   **The `SPEVENT.lParam` value represents a pointer to a string**.
>   For example, the TTS bookmark event (i.e., `SPEI_TTS_BOOKMARK`) includes a pointer the bookmark name, so the `lParam` type is `SPET_LPARAM_IS_STRING`.
>   **The user must call `CoTaskMemFree` on the `lParam` member (as pointer) to release the associated memory.**

Which means the memory pointed to by the `lParam` MUST by allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc()` (or related function), which `std::wstring` is not, so you cannot just pass the `std::wstring::c_str()` pointer in the `lParam`, you must make a copy to a CoTask-allocated memory block.

Also, the [`SPEI_TTS_BOOKMARK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee431845(v=vs.85)) says:

> SPEI_TTS_BOOKMARK
>   The bookmark element is used to insert a bookmark into the output stream. If an application specifies interest in bookmark events, it will receive the bookmark events during synthesis. `wParam` is the current bookmark name (in base 10) converted to a long integer. **If name of current bookmark is not an integer, `wParam` will be zero. `lParam` is the bookmark string. `elParamType` has to be `SPET_LPARAM_IS_STRING`.**

So, with that said, try this instead:

```
wstring wsBookmark = L"MyBookmark";

UINT size = (wsBookmark.size() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t);

wchar_t *ptr = (wchar_t*) CoTaskMemAlloc(size);
CopyMemory(ptr, wsBookmark.c_str(), size);

CSpEvent nBookmarkEvent;
nBookmarkEvent.eEventId = SPEI_TTS_BOOKMARK;
nBookmarkEvent.elParamType = SPET_LPARAM_IS_STRING;
nBookmarkEvent.ullAudioStreamOffset = 0;
nBookmarkEvent.wParam = 0;
nBookmarkEvent.lParam = (LPARAM) ptr;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've put the (LPARAM)ptr into the wParam while it should be in the lParam, so the 2 should just be switched. Then it works fantastic. Thank you so much, I wouldn't have been able to figure that out myself yet!

Comment: @tmighty I corrected the mistake in my answer. And yes, the allocated memory needs to be freed, but in this case the [`CSpEvent`'s destructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee450700(v=vs.85)) will handle that for you.